# Как получить доступ к свойству связанной модели, имеющей отношение многие ко многим

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

У меня есть модель фотографий связанная с несколькими другими моделями. (полиморфная связь многие ко многим)

В частности с моделью объекта недвижимости

```
public function property(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Property::class, 'relation_model', 'files_relation', 'relation_model_id', 'file_id');
}
```

И модель объекта недвижимости, связанного с фотографиями.

```
public function photo(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany
{
    return $this
        ->morphToMany(
            FileModel::class,
            'relation_model',
            'files_relation',
            'relation_model_id',
            'file_id'
        )
        ->withPivot('order')
        ->orderByPivot('order', 'asc');
}
```

Далее я делаю запрос на получение всех объектов

```
$all = Property::with([
    'photo' => function ($query) {
        $query->first();
    },
    'route'
])->get();
```

Мне возвращается массив в таком виде
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`route` в массиве это тоже полиморфная связь но один к одному.

Если я обращусь `$all->first()->route` то получу его содержимое.

Но если я попробую сделать то же самое, чтобы получить связанную модель фотографий, то там будет пусто

```
$all->first()->photo // null
```

хотя, как можете видеть на скрине, в возвращаемом списке есть свойство `photo`, и оно не пустое

Только изучаю Laravel и не понимаю почему так происходит, может быть нужно вызвать какой-то дополнительный метод прежде чем путаться обратиться к `photo`.

Получить свойство объекта photo пока могу с помощью таких манипуляций

```
$all->first()->toArray()['photo'];
```

Но я подготавливаю ресурс для API, и хотелось бы использовать официальное чистое решение и не делать самописные методы для построения нужного ответа.

Сейчас код моего ресурса выглядит так

```
public function toArray($request): array
{
    return [
        'address' => $this->address,
        'city' => $this->city,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'object_type' => $this->object_type,
        'price' => $this->price,
        'slug' => $this->route->slug,
        'photo' => PropertyTeaserPhotoResource::collection($this->photo),
        'options' => json_decode($this->options)
    ];
}
```

Ну и при попытке получить коллекцию фото я вижу ошибку.

```
message: "Call to a member function first() on null"
```

Answer (score 0):

Как всегда подвела собственная невнимательность.
В таблице модели объекта недвижимости было поле `photo`. Именно его я видел при выводе коллекции. А когда получал

```
Property::with([
    'photo' => function ($query) {
        $query->first();
    },
    'route'
])->get();
```

То обращался уже к методу 'photo' отсюда и кализия